How do I hardcode `TERM` for CLI emacs in elisp?
The TERM variable is not set correctly for my emacs. I like to override it using elisp.
I am currently using:
(setenv "TERM" "xterm-kitty")

But this does not seem to work.
PS: I'm running emacs using junest, which seems to be doing some magic that overrides my TERM=... emacs invocation. Hence the need to override the terminfo from elisp.

Pls clarify the meaning of "does not seem to work", is that that using (getenv "TERM") gives you something different from xterm-kitty?

@Hi-Angel I fixed the problem from the junest side. But what I meant was that emacs still showed in wrong colors even though I had used (setenv "TERM" "xterm-kitty"). (I use 24 bit true colors which need the special terminfo.)

Oh, great to hear you solved it! Please describe your solution, so if somebody stumbles upon the same problem they might use your knowledge, and also to "close" the question as answered

@Hi-Angel I am not really sure what the problem was in the first place. I solved it by adding export TERM=... to .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc. Previously, I used ssh host -t TERM=... emacs.
